# Count repeating names in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables: Customer and ParkingTransaction. I want to show the top 10 customers who use the lot most often. 'CustomerKey' in the ParkingTrasaction table is the FK that connects ParkingTransaction to Customer. I have written the following code which counts the most used CustomerKey in the ParkingTransaction table, and it works fine...

```
SELECT TOP 10 CustomerKey
, count(*) as 'Usage'
  FROM ParkingTransaction
  GROUP BY CustomerKey
  HAVING (count(CustomerKey) > 0)
  ORDER BY 'Usage' DESC
```

This is my output

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D6x8.png)

The problem I am facing is this: I want to pull the FirstName and LastName fields from the Customer table, instead of sorting by just the CustomerKey. I have messed around with JOINS, but haven't come up with a solution yet.

Thanks!

Comment: `HAVING (count(CustomerKey) > 0)` is redundant. You group by `CustomerKey`, so every group will consist of at least 1 row. It can never be 0 or less.

Comment: When did MySQL start supporting the SQL Server style `SELECT TOP n ...`?  (oops, that's a question and not a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses `LIMIT` not `TOP`.

```
SELECT  a.FirstName, a.LastName,
        COUNT(*) as `Usage`
FROM    Customer a
        INNER JOIN ParkingTransaction b
            ON a.CustomerKey = b.CustomerKey
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName
ORDER BY `Usage` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

since the query is using `INNER JOIN`, `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` is unneccessary in this case.

Comment: OP: Note that parking transactions that don't have a matching customer will not be returned (INNER JOIN). Perfect if that's what you're going for.

Comment: @showdev Yes. but in the original query the OP uses `HAVING (count(CustomerKey) > 0)` which filters the customer that has no transaction yet.

Comment: True. But what about transactions that have no matching customer (e.g. the Customer was deleted but the transaction remains.) Personally, I would rather see that a customer has 0 transactions and see that a transaction has an unknown customer rather than not see transactions that don't have associated customers. Matter of preference, though. Nice job +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT CustomerKey, c.firstname, c.lastname, count(*) as 'Usage'
FROM ParkingTransaction pt join
     customer c
     on pt.customerkey = c.customerkey
GROUP BY pt.CustomerKey, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
ORDER BY 'Usage' DESC
limit 10
```

Comment: kindly check the syntax before posting :)

Comment: one more thing, the having clause in your query doesn't make sense since inner join don't shows records that is not present on both sides.

Comment: @Be Happy it doesn't make sense in the original query either.

Comment: @ypercube can you combine `TOP` and `LIMIT`?